# Update object value in array of objects React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have such array with fields id and title in object

```
const cols = [
    {
      id: 0,
      title: "TODO"
    }, {
      id: 1,
      title: "InProgress"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      title: "Testing"
    }, {
      id: 3,
      title: "Done"
    },
  ]
```

I have a state: `const [colArray, setColArray] = useState(cols);`

And I need to find object in this array by id and put into this object new `title` value.

I tried this:

```
 const EditColName = () => {
    setColArray(prevState => [...prevState, colArray.filter(item => item.id === editColId){ title: newTitle}])
  }
```

But i have an error

```
TS2345: Argument of type '(prevState: { id: number; title: string; }[]) => ({ id: number; title: string; } | { id: number; title: string; }[] | { title: string; })[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<{ id: number; title: string; }[]>'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a spread operator on the previous state, but not the filtered array.  So you are getting a type error because your data has an array of your 'cols' and then a nested array of the filtered results.

If you just want to set the colArray to the filter then don't use the previous state:

```
setColArray(colArray.filter(item => item.id === editColId))
```

Or if you do:

```
setColArray(prevState => [...prevState, ....colArray.filter(item => item.id === editColId), { title: newTitle}])
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to find object with matching `id` (use [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)) and pass into the array overriding value of `title` (use spread operator).

```
 const EditColName = () => {
    setColArray(prevState => [...prevState, { ... prevState.find(item => item.id === editColId)! , title: newTitle }])
  }
```

`.find()` returns undefined in some cases (when no array item matches the property). So you have to use TS [`non null assertion operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) (!) to let TS know that there will be definitely be a value this time.